# Unexpected error: CLIENT_ERROR on Openshift

Tags: openshift-origin

Following the guide at https://www.openshift.com/developers/download-cartridges i wanted to try installing the CDK to see what it brings to the table. Unfortunately, I was unable to install the cartridge because of the following error:

```
Unexpected error: CLIENT_ERROR: Download of 'http://cdk-claytondev.rhcloud.com/archive/2ccd7a3a7762e4ebb873c0d64a247b180e0600b8/cdk.zip' exceeded Content-Length of 9728. Download aborted.
```

Execute rhc create-app cdk http://cdk-claytondev.rhcloud.com/manifest/2ccd7a3a7762e4ebb873c0d64a247b180e0600b8 against a local installation of OpenShift Origin. Or try to create an App throught the web console (again on a local installation, both are untested on rhcloud).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was an issue on OpenShift Online also, which got fixed, but is still an issue on OpenShift Origin.  Here is the bugzilla ticket for this issue (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1017776), I suggest you add your email address to it to be notified as they make progress against fixing it.